# Limited selection of 'Person or Group' pickable from mobile browser

Tags: list, person, mobile-view

I have a Sharepoint List with a "Person or Group" column (required, no multi-select, people only, all-users) and a default view.

On the desktop browser the name picker allows typing any name, with 'Ctrl-k' completion:

[image: Screenshot from desktop browser]

**However**, on a mobile (iOS Safari) the picker is displayed as a drop down list, with only a very limited number of name choices:

[image: Screenshot from Safari browser]

Question is, how can mobile users choose from the full selection of names?  It's only showing names up to "Andrew" but there are many more names in the org.

Thanks in advance!